# Use on CMD 'make copy' make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: cmd, makefile

I have a problem when i would like to build WEB package from repostory.

```
copy forbidden.html build\testing\forbidden.html
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, copy forbidden.html build\testing\forbidden.html, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:16: copy] Error 2
```

can someone help me with this, what could be the problem?

I use on git-local\bin on Path and when i delete then working the make copy on cmd.

$(info $(SHELL)) I added to makefile on the shell give back git_local\bin\sh.exe

when I deleted git from the path, only sh.exe appeared

"The path of your file has a space in its name, which means you have to surround the path which contains spaces with quotation marks." I tried but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU `make` on Windows will prefer to run a POSIX shell, `sh.exe`, if it can be found on the PATH.  If it can't be found, then `make` will fall back to `cmd.exe`.

The error you show implies that make found a `sh.exe` on your `PATH` and so is using that.  Because make is not using `cmd.exe` you can't run any `cmd.exe` built-in programs like `copy` in your recipe.

If you always want your makefile to use `cmd.exe` with this makefile, you can specify that's what you want by adding this to your makefile:

```
SHELL := cmd.exe
```

Comment: Thanks this process is working good when i write on makfile this command :)